# How to convince immigration officers on accommodation while on a travel trip availing couchsurfing?

Tags: indian-citizens, proof-of-accommodation, couchsurfing

I'm from India and I was wondering how to get around the situation, when I am going for a travel trip to a country (any country for that matter) abroad, but haven't booked a hotel as I am planning to do a couchsurfing. The period of stay could vary between 5 days to 1 month, out of which, suppose I received confirmation of stay for an initial couple of days from a couch surfer.

1)In such a scenario, how do I clear the interview by the immigration officer when asked to provide my accommodation arrangements? Will simply telling the truth about relying on couchsurfing be wise to get clearnce by the officer?
2)Is it even an option to book a hotel through websites in advance and cancel the booking after I get clearance from the immigration officer? In that case, will I be liable to pay cancellation charges- or-the whole booking amount gets deducted from my credit card account?

The questions might sound silly to many, but I am seriously looking for your guidance on this as I will be planning visit to different countries depending mostly on couchsurfing for accommodation. Thanks in advance.

Additional Notes: Currently I hold a B1 valid for 9 more years. I have visited UK and USA once and twice respectively on business purpose- if this info helps. And I'll be planning for travel trip to USA/UK/Europe/south east Asia

Comment: Which country(ies) are you talking about?

Comment: I will probably get flagged for this, but the simple truth is that people from your country seem have somewhat more difficulty getting visas to other countries. Couple that with things like couch surfing being a _relatively_ new phenomenon, I can foresee difficulties for your travel plans.

Comment: As many countries ask visa nationals to provide accommodation and other details (financial etc.) in the process of visa application/entry, couchsurfing may not be seen as an acceptable alternative, suggesting that you are unable to afford entirely your trip.

Comment: You would as a minimum have to provide the addresses where you plan to couchsurf - or are you saying you’d stay with strangers or in places found on the internet?

Comment: " travel trip" and "couchsurfing" are not common thing to to together, so you need to explain a lot.

Comment: Check whether you even need to provide evidence of travel plans (flights and accommodation) as part of the visa application for the country you wish to visit. I recall seeing information on this site (not sure if it was just a comment or an answer) stating that, for the UK, the guidance for visa applications actually advises **against** booking flights and accommodation before the visa has been approved, so you don't risk losing money on bookings that aren't (fully) refundable.